# Can't change com.google.android.material.chip.Chip change press color

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-components, android-chips

I programmatically Chips (Material Components), use `setChipBackgroundColor` change chip state press color but it's have two press color effect, i want to remove default press gray color

1. my custom press (#daecff)
2. default press color (gray)

thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGIUM.jpg

```xml
Chip chip = new Chip(context);
chip.setText(name);
chip.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
chip.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.chip_color));
chip.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
chip.setChipStrokeColorResource(R.color.chip_color);
chip.setChipStrokeWidth(5);
chip.setChipBackgroundColor(
    ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.bg_chip)
);
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#daecff"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the **`setRippleColor`** method:

```
chip.setRippleColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.my_selector));
```

with something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
  <item android:alpha="@dimen/mtrl_low_ripple_pressed_alpha" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="@dimen/mtrl_low_ripple_focused_alpha" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_focused="true" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="@dimen/mtrl_low_ripple_focused_alpha" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="@dimen/mtrl_low_ripple_hovered_alpha" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="@dimen/mtrl_low_ripple_default_alpha" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Also you have to check the selector used in the **`setChipBackgroundColor`** method,  in particular the color used for the `selected` state:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- 24% opacity -->
  <item android:alpha="0.24" android:color="@color/custom" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
  ....
</selector>
```